# Write email address with an underline between words

Tags: underline, email

I need to include an email address with an underline between words in this form: `foo_bar@gmail.com`, but latex was considering the underline being for a subscript in math mode.

I used `\author{Name\corresp{\email{foo_bar@gmail.com}}}`.

The console reports the error:

> Missing $ inserted. ...

What is this error and what's causing it, moreover what should be changed in my file to fix this?

Comment: Use `\_` instead of `_`

Comment: _ is expected to be seen in math mode; that's why it complains about missing $

Comment: @egreg thank you! I am ashamed for not having thought of this!

Answer (score 1):

Your command should be:

`\author{Name\corresp{\email{foo\_bar@gmail.com}}}`

Answer (score 1):

Pah!  The problem is whatever documentclass/style file you are using has a bad definition of `\email`.   Strictly speaking it is not your problem, and instead you should contact whatever journal/publisher provides the class/style to get them to fix the problem.

What they (and you when necessary) should really use is `\usepackage{url}` and then instead of their bad `\email`, just code  `\protect\url{foo_bar@gmail.com}`.

So, in standard LaTeX the author definition is `\author{Name\thanks{\protect\url{foo_bar@gmail.com}}}`

(Although best practice email is `\url{mailto:foo_bar@gmail.com}` )